# Determine the number of connected acyclic graph with 10 vertices and 10 edges, how and why

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Determine the number of connected acyclic graphs with 10 vertices and
>   10 edges.

Please if someone can explain how and why, thank you.

Comment: Connected acyclic graphs? Those are also called trees. But in any tree the number of vertices is exactly one more than the number of edges. So the answer is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connected acyclic graph is a tree.

A tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges.

Hence there are no connected acyclic graphs  with $10$ vertices and $10$ edges.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Assuming that the associated vertices are connected , it means that the question should be set with 10 vertices and 9 edges?

Comment: @Ivan The question should be set in such a way to reflect the problem you want to solve. We can't know which problem you want to solve until you ask a question...  Do you want to know how many trees are there with $n$ vertices? Then you can see [Enumeration of Trees on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Enumeration)